# LuaRocks Installation in Win 10 does nothing

Tags: lua, lua-table

I just started learning Lua few days ago.

My system:

```
Windows 10
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

I downloaded and unzipped [LuaRocks-3.5.0-Windows-64.zip](http://luarocks.github.io/luarocks/releases/luarocks-3.5.0-windows-64.zip). After clicking the exe and allowing the running permission, I could see a flickering command prompt. It just disappeared.

What shall I do next to install it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next or actually first step is obviously to read the manual.

Let me quote https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows

> unpack it and you'll have a luarocks.exe ready to use.

You do not have to "install" luarocks. The zip file contains two executables. Put them in a folder and ideally add that folder to your PATH system variable.

Once you've downloaded and extracted the archive read

https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Using-LuaRocks

That's command line tools. You run them from the command line. Double-clicking them won't do much as you don't provide any options/arguments like that.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your inspirational help.